# Snowflake select query to return data in json format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am making a select call on a table and it always returns 1 row. I would like to get the data in json format.

```
{
  "column_name1": "value1",
  "column_name2": "value2",
}
```

Does snowflake query allows anything like this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[object_construct](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/object_construct.html) is the way to go for this.

For example,

```
select object_construct(*) from t1;
```

Comment: The only problem is that it doesn't return the columns whose values are null, which is a issue in my use case

Comment: for people from the future, there is also OBJECT_CONSTRUCT_KEEP_NULL(*)